# Set default path/route for mvc images/styles/scripts helpers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I use MVC helpers like this: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` to add styles on the page, but I don't like this relative path everywhere. And it's very hard to fix all occcurentcies, if I change folder structure.

Could I configure somewhere to setup that `@Styles` should map to `'~/Content'` and `@Scripts` to `~/Scripts` to be able instead of `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` write just 
`@Styles.Render("main.css")` for example?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is not a helper but a bundle. Bundles are defined inside a virtual path in ISS when you disable debug.

For example:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include("~/My/Css/File.css"));
```

Will configure a virtual path in `/Content/css` in IIS.

You can change the virtual path to whatever you want.